# what do "free to change" and "but of all models" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What do "free to change" and "but of all models" mean in this sentence "Topologists, for example, do not study the singularities structuring the possibility space of a model free to change in its temperature and its pressure, but of all models with two degrees of freedom whatever these may be."?

Comment: It's hard to answer this without any information about where your difficulty lies. Neither _free to change_ nor _but of all models_ is a self-contained constituent of the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Topologists, for example, do not study the singularities structuring the possibility space of a model free to change in its temperature and its pressure, but of all models with two degrees of freedom whatever these may be."*

Firstly you need to understand the structure of the sentence as follows:

"Topologists do not study the singularities structuring the possibility space of a ***specific*** model (with two degrees of freedom), but (instead they study the possibility space) of ***all*** models with two degrees of freedom, whatever these (degrees of freedom) may be."

The specific case is:

"a model that is free to change in its temperature and its pressure"

and, of course the two degrees of freedom are temperature and pressure.

The reasoning behind this statement is that topologists are pure mathematicians not engineers.  They generalise as much as possible. It is up to the applied mathematicians to show how the results can be used in real life situations.

I hope this helps.